# Really basic puzzle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am sure you will be able to find this puzzle out easily.

## Let's Begin!

1. I am long as infinity
2. I can be round or a rectangle
3. People like me when I go inside them
4. I come in many flavors
5. I don't have a reason *why*, just a meal
6. You can find me partnered with math
7. Me - *e*

Basic, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> Pi

I am long as infinity

> Infinite decimal expansion

I can be round or a rectangle

> Pi is defined based on circles, which are round. An uppercase $\Pi$ looks like a rectangle.

People like me when I go inside them

> Pie tastes good.

I come in many flavors / I don't have a reason why, just a meal

> Apple, cherry, blueberry, pumpkin, etc.

You can find me partnered with math

> Obvious.

Me - e

> The letter "e" is removed from "pie" to get "pi".

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Pi (3.14159265)

I am long as infinity

> It is irrational an goes on forever.

I can be round or a rectangle

> I am not sure about the rectangle part, but pi is found in circles and pie is circular.

People like me when I go inside them

> Pie tastes good.

I come in many flavors

> Pecan, ckicken-pot, pumpkin, ect...

I don't have a reason why, just a meal

> It is food.

You can find me partnered with math

> Pi is a number.

Me - e

> e is another irrational number.

Regarding the "easy" part,

> It is easy as pie!

Comment: 13 seconds after me :)

Comment: Ahhh, sniped  :D

Comment: The easy part wasn't a hint...